# Gradle fails with not a valid response from a Gradle Plugin Resolution Service: content type is 'text/html', expected 'application/json'

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, proxy

I am using IntelliJ and am behind a firewall when at the work office.  I have configured IntelliJ to use the automatic URL config for the proxy and this seems to be working but I get this error when behind the proxy, but when not using the proxy it works as expected.

```
Error:(20, 0) The response from https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle/2.10/plugin/use/org.flywaydb.flyway/4.0.3 was not a valid response from a Gradle Plugin Resolution Service: content type is 'text/html', expected 'application/json'
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:  I forgot to mention I have the following setup in my gradle.properties, obviously with real info and not *****

```
systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=******
systemProp.https.proxyHost=http://*****/
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
systemProp.http.proxyUser=******
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=****
```

After changing that to be

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=***
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
systemProp.http.proxyUser=***
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=**
systemProp.https.proxyHost=**
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
systemProp.https.proxyUser=**
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=**
```

I now get this erro:

```
Error:(20, 0) The response from https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle/3.0/plugin/use/org.flywaydb.flyway/4.0.3 was not a valid response from a Gradle Plugin Resolution Service: content type is 'text/html', expected 'application/json' (status code: 407)
```

But using the same setting in IntelliJ and setting the proxy manually it passes its test (click the config test button in settings)

Comment: You'll have to configure Gradle specifically to use your proxy (I assume you are behind a proxy).

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy

Comment: I forgot to mention that in my question, yes I have set that up

Comment: Have you solved this issue.. I have the same issue ..

Comment: Have you solved this issue.. I have the same issue too

Comment: @DenverCoder9 WHAT DID YOU SEE?!

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? I'm facing same issue.